# Finding the inverse of a rational function (quadratic dividend and divisor)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inverse-function

[image: problem]

I've solved functions where it has a linear dividend and divisor only before and this is pretty new to me. I tried solving this by using what I've learnt in quadratics and polynomials but I keep going into a circle. Can anyone teach me on how would you go on solving a function where both the dividend and divisor are quadratics? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$f(x)=\frac{2x^2+7x-4}{x^2+x-2}$

$=2+\frac{5x}{x^2+x-2}=y$

you solve for $x \in(-\infty,-2)$

$,(-2,1)$  and $(1,+\infty)$.

Comment: May I ask you to direct me to any learning resources that might help me understand this even more?

Answer (score 0):

Let $y$ be a real. You want to solve : $f(x)=y$. This means :
\begin{align}
  \frac{(2x-1)(x+4)}{(x-1)(x+2)} &=y\iff (2x-1)(x+4)=y(x-1)(x+2) \\
  \iff 2x^2+7x-4=yx^2+yx-2 \\
  \iff (2-y)x^2+(7-y)x-2=0
\end{align}
If $y\ne 2$, discriminant is : $$\Delta=(7-y)^2+8(2-y)=y^2-22y+65=(y-11)^2-56=(y-11-\sqrt{56})(y-11+\sqrt{56})$$
So :
 - if $y\in\left]11-\sqrt{56},11+\sqrt{56}\right[$, $\Delta<0$ and the equation has no solution, meaning $y$ doesn't have a pre-image;
 - if $y=11\pm\sqrt{56}$, the equation has one solution $x=-\frac{7-y}{4-2y}$,
 - if $y\in\left]-\infty,11-\sqrt{56}\right[ \cup \left]11+\sqrt{56},+\infty\right[$, the equation has two solutions :
$$x=\frac{-(7-y)\pm \sqrt{y^2-22y+65}}{2(2-y)}$$
if $y=2$, the equation reduces to $5x-2=0$ so $x=\frac25$.